# jQuery Append on document load, appends two times and seems not to wait until document is loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, append, document-ready

I'm trying to create a navigation FX on the header's nav appending an hr and animating its width but I have two problems:

1. Before the appending function I try to get the target width but the value returned is lower than the real width -- [Solved by @Maxzeroedge]: I should have get the padding value too
2. The hr it's appended two times

This is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.onPage').append('<hr/>');
    var targetWi = $('.onPage').width();
    $('.onPage hr').animate({
        'width':targetWi
    }, 2000)
})
```

I'm sure the 2 problems are related and may have something to do with the document loading process,but I've tried different document jQuery listeners and I'm getting the same result.

Thanks for reading!

Comment: Maybe you have more than one element that matches `.onPage`?

Comment: Did you have append anywhere else too? Also, reason for getting lower value could be that you aren't getting the padding or margin values.

Comment: You have to provide relevant HTML markup in question. BTW, not sure what you are expecting with animating a HR width, HR by default is a block element, meaning taking all parent's width

Comment: Hi @FrédéricHamidi, thanks! I've checked it and it doesn't. I add the class to the target, by ID,  with jquery before executing this lines

Comment: Can you post your HTML ??

Comment: @Maxzeroedge thanks, you're right! The width problem is due to not getting the padding values. But why it's beeing appended two times?

Comment: @nach Without seeing all relevant code, how can we know???

Comment: @A.Wolff It's a simple navigation menu in html5 <nav><ul><li class="onPage"><a>...

Comment: @nach as you can see it works as expected http://jsfiddle.net/g1r91hyt/ so again, your issue is coming from somewhere else

Comment: @nach It will append as many times as `$('.onPage').length`

Comment: One good way to find out, would be to use console.log("some text or element here"); at different parts of your code, starting with the append in document ready function. It will give you some idea for debugging.

Comment: @Maxzeroedge just did it, and it console loged 2 times, so  $(window).load(...) its executed twice. It's weird

Comment: @TouPye Thanks just checked and I can confirm that it only appears 1 time on the document

Comment: @nach, window.load or document.ready? Also, right now, I can't figure out anything more. A little more code, maybe a simplified jsfiddle may help.

Comment: Sorry guys it was my mistake. The script file was loaded twice (due to other ajax navigation script I've created) , that's why the append were executing two times. Thanks for your help! Specialy @Maxzeroedge

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help! I'ts solved

The first problem it's worth to be explained because it could be a common mistake:

**Allways think about paddings when your getting widths !**

The second problem was related with a double script loading (my bad)

Thanks for your time!